# Can I safely delete the "Deleted Users" directory after an upgrade or a data transfer?

Tags: macos

I have just transferred data from my old MacBook Air to my new MacBook Pro. There is now a `Deleted Users` Directory in the `/Users` directory. Can this be safely deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Deleted Users directory contains the contents of Home folders of deleted users, usually in the form of disk images. So unless those users had some documents/pictures you want to keep, you can delete it. Your own programs never rely on data in the Home folders of other users - you don't even have access to it, except as an administrator.